# can't get UILexicon on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm developing and iOS custom keyboard, and want to import system text replacement.

I'm importing as following:

```
UIInputViewController()
            .requestSupplementaryLexiconWithCompletion({
    lexicon in
    print("==== entries.count: \(lexicon.entries.count)")
})
```

and the entries.count is 0.
I've confirmed that there already has 2 text shortcuts in "Text Replacement" configure, why?

Comment: Same problem here, except I'm trying to make it suggest based on the common words dictionary. I do exactly what they say, and it doesn't work.